# Using grails to dynamically create Divs

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to be able to dynamically create divs using grails. Something like

```
<g:each in="${userInstanceList}" status="i" var="userInstance">
<div id="div${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "id")}"
${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "message")}
</div>
</g:each>
```

Of course, that is terribly wrong and doesn't address styling issues.
Since Grails is relatively new, I cannot find any recourses on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with the sample posted?

Comment: Yeah, the only thing wrong I see is that you didn't close your initial div tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your sample runs well (technically). In my understanding, you want to create some kind of list of "items", which is got from the database, and every item div needs an unique `id` for javascript work with. It's not very good to name a div "div1", "div2" but I think you can easily work around it.

My proposed solution:

```
<g:each in="${userInstanceList}" status="i" var="userInstance">
<div id="item${userInstance.id}" class="Item" >
${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "message")}
</div>
</g:each>
```